# Type or namespace could not be found for a referenced project in the same solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am getting this unbelievably annoying issue in VS 2017. Somehow these kinds of issues are always plaguing me..

I opened up my solution today which contains several projects to find that one was just missing for no reason (it is always there when I open the solution).

So I simply re-added the project by right-clicking Solution explorer and adding an existing project - easy.

Now, when I try to run that project (`OrderGetter`), it fails to build with

> The type or namespace name 'Utilities' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

`Utilties` is another project in my solution:

[image]

It definitely exists and has always worked in the past. Why must this issue come and happen now?

Eveb weirder, The error keeps disappearing from the errors window, but when I try to build I get the popup telling me I have errors, and I have to check the output window to see what is going on.

I have tried the following:

- Clean solution
- Clean project
- Build/Rebuild solution
- Build/Rebuild projecct
- Close all tabs, restart VS
- Remove/re-add reference
- Unload project, delete reference from the `csproj` file and then re add it in the VS UI before reloading the project

  - Checked that the csproj GUIDs match

I can see the following in `Solution.sln`:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "MVCQCPage", "MVCQCPage\MVCQCPage.csproj", "{FF699AAD-EA97-4984-9DB2-70F2CA41CA16}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "SharedLibrary", "SharedLibrary\SharedLibrary.csproj", "{0E6DE04C-97A2-4C18-AB83-098C383DF9C7}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "AspNet.Identity.SQLite", "..\..\..\..\Downloads\Firefox\Asp.Net.Identity.SQLite-master\Asp.Net.Identity.SQLite-master\AspNet.Identity.SQLite\AspNet.Identity.SQLite.csproj", "{35DAC40A-38D0-43BD-8DCF-34E4061F0A75}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "AspNet.Identity.SQLite.EF", "..\..\..\..\Downloads\Firefox\Asp.Net.Identity.SQLite-master\Asp.Net.Identity.SQLite-master\AspNet.Identity.SQLite.EF\AspNet.Identity.SQLite.EF.csproj", "{D34D1279-F264-4A90-B4A5-2AAE4DE5D0D6}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "PublicSite", "..\..\..\..\Downloads\Firefox\Asp.Net.Identity.SQLite-master\Asp.Net.Identity.SQLite-master\PublicSite\PublicSite.csproj", "{18D9B36C-50A0-4753-9522-A1C282C70B3E}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Utilities", "Utilities\Utilities.csproj", "{4473F366-D894-425D-AFE2-75EC883AC0E7}"
EndProject
Project("{F5034706-568F-408A-B7B3-4D38C6DB8A32}") = "Scripts", "Scripts\Scripts.pssproj", "{6CAFC0C6-A428-4D30-A9F9-700E829FEA51}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "TurboTime", "TurboTime\TurboTime.csproj", "{05FFA6B7-8ACE-4FDF-83DB-75FBF7C46E64}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "TurboTimeConsole", "TurboTimeConsole\TurboTimeConsole.csproj", "{F5B79240-155C-4E8B-B8F7-BFFBC9EFE9EB}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "OrderGetter", "OrderGetter\OrderGetter.csproj", "{BBD80E29-721A-4423-A21E-4B6C51D153FF}"
EndProject
```

And in `Utilites.csproj` I can see that the GUId is

```
<ProjectGuid>{4473F366-D894-425D-AFE2-75EC883AC0E7}</ProjectGuid>
```

And that `OrderGetter.csproj` is referencing

```
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Utilities\Utilities.csproj">
  <Project>{4473f366-d894-425d-afe2-75ec883ac0e7}</Project>
  <Name>Utilities</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

So the GUIDs are the same except for one being upper case and the other lower case. What does that mean?

You can clearly see that the project is definitely being referenced:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: close your VS, delete the .vs-folder at the root of your repo and the bin/objs of all projects. check that the frameworks of the projects are compatible and try again

Comment: @D.J. That doesn't seem to be working for me. The frameworks should all be compatible - `Utilties` just contains simple string extensions and it has always worked before today... I just don't understand why this always has to happen to me

Comment: The error message contains help about two different possible resolutions. You may need one (reference), the other (using directive) or *both* to fix the error.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have both a reference and a using directive. The error window stays empty but the project fails to build

Comment: What is the version of your Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

If the above does not help, you can open the solution as well as the project files in a text editor and check if the project file have the correct references set.

Each project has a unique GUID

```
<ProjectGuid>{12D33B77-30A1-4D07-9DA4-8789AF6746F5}</ProjectGuid>
```

the referencing project uses this GUID along with the path to reference this project:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Data Binding Demo\C#\databindinglab.csproj">
  <Project>{12D33B77-30A1-4D07-9DA4-8789AF6746F5}</Project>
  <Name>databindinglab</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```

Check the affected projects and make sure file names and GUIDs match.

If this does not help, remove all references, save and close the project and then add each reference again.

Comment: The GUIDs are the same except that in `OrderGetter.csproj` its all in lower case (I updated the question) - does that make a difference? I have tried re-adding references but with no effect...

Comment: Solution and project file looks fine. GUIDs match (case is ignored by the build system afaik). From this perspective I can't see anything wrong with it.